# When I try to use the RGoogleAnalytics R package I get OAuth issues

Tags: r, oauth, google-analytics

Despite getting this message on the web browser :Authentication complete. Please close this page and return to **R**.

I get this in **R** and it fails to get a token ?

```
Authentication complete.
Error in oauth2.0_access_token(endpoint, app, code = code, user_params = user_params,  : 
  Unauthorized (HTTP 401). Failed to get an access token.
```

simple R script

Comment: I do not understand in what function you have problem, `ValidateToken`?, `Auth`?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication complete.
Error in oauth2.0_access_token(endpoint, app, code = code, user_params = user_params,  : 
  Unauthorized (HTTP 401). Failed to get an access token.

is the error message but I call this :token <- Auth(client.id,client.secret)